# How to Encode and Decode video from camera in real time for android?

Tags: android, decode, encode, android-mediacodec

I am previewing with SurfaceView. I need to endcode the video and send it for decoding in real time. 10+ API level would accepted for me.

Could any one help ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? encode and then decode? why? Also, API10 was released on December 6, 2010 - its ancient. if you can target API16 then Android's built-in MediaCodec is the way to go.

Comment: I want to make a video call app.. after encoding I want to transfer the data and will decode in receiver end.